# my USB mic is on an arm and connected through a shock absorber, still picks up noise from my mouse

Tags: noise

I have a Mic [Uhuru USB](http://www.uhurumobility.com/Home/Products/detail/code/2019042301) attached using its arm and then has a spider web shock absorber which I assume is to cancel the noise from my desk.
I notice when playing games, especially when I pick the mouse up and put it back down it's making a noise that registers and is really hard to remove in post. It's not a constant noise though.
I have bought a mouse pad to try improve canceling from the source, but is it a problem with my mic to be picking that sound up?

Any other suggestions to fix it? Should I just opt for more expensive arm and shocks, or can I get away with just detaching it from my desk and getting a stand or something for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to fasten the arm to something else, not connected physically to the desk.

I have a mic very similar to that [I bought it just to answer questions like this] & the 'shock absorbing' cradle is actually more resonant than a regular solid mic stand. As they have no means by which they can be mounted to a regular mic stand/thread, you have no real choice other than to move it away from noise transmission sources, or just tape it to a proper stand;)

Good cradles are not cheap in the slightest. This is mine - https://www.andertons.co.uk/recording/recording-microphones/microphone-accessories/shockmounts-pop-filters/neumann-ea87-shock-mount-for-u87

*Ahhh…* I noticed the base **is** threaded. That means it will fit on a regular hollow mic adapter - one with room for the cable through the middle. You'd probably have to go to a music retailer to check thread sizes.

[image] [image]

Comment: ah, okay, that shock mount is really expensive! :) not an option for me. but my mic is the same as yours, it's just the USB version. so, my best option is to get a stand and put it away... I was wondering if I can get away with a cheep one though? (it needs to support the arm extending to the side and the mic would be kind of heavy on it?

Comment: Good shock mounts **are** expensive. They need to be balanced to the weight of the mic & not just be some random rubber band that straps round the mic body. Note the Neumann cradle doesn't touch the body at all, it's screwed in by the thread underneath, making the isolation as good as humanly possible. I have actually tried my own U87 in the cheap shock mount (it was a squeeze, but I persuaded it;) & it's far worse than just using the simple clip in my answer. The free 'fix' is just clamp it to something else.